# Webrequest timeout issue

Tags: c#, webrequest

I have an issue with webrequest timeout parameter. I'm calling a website in IIS to execute some post APIs to external site. The API calls are to delete existing csvs on staging server, upload new version and execute upsert on objects relevant to those csvs.

Problem is sometimes the timeout set is enough and the whole process completes successfully.
Other times, its not enough and fails. I have no way of calculating how much time it takes to send a response. I need to process a DB update after I receive a response. How do I dynamically change the timeout param. I searched and found the answer to be no. Hoping for some other ideas.

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SERVICE_BASE_URL);
                request.Timeout = 1000000;
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.

                using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    
                    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    // Read the content.
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    // Display the content of response.
                    Log.Debug(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Response is: ") + reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
                response.Close();
```

Comment: Is this an MVC application?

Comment: Note: do not use WebRequest - it is obsolete in .NET 6. Use HttpClient instead.

Comment: @AkshayBheda - its not an MVC application. It's a console app in .Net5.0 which in turn calls the website (.Net Core) to execute APIs.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, thanks for the suggestion. I switched to HttpClient and added this line  for timeout: client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;                                              Did a test and it is waiting for the response now and not timing out. Thanks!